# Fruit score leaderboard

Tags: html, css

I made a basic website to practice HTML and CSS that will display 3 fruits with their given scores in an Olympic podium sort of way.

Have I used any bad practices and what I should do instead?

What can I do to fully optimize and shorten my code?

How readable is my code? How can I make it more readable?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .bronze {
            transform: scale(0.75);
        }

        .bronze span {
            background-color: #CD7F32;
        }

        .gold span {
            background-color: #FFD700;
        }

        .silver {
            transform: scale(0.75);
        }

        .silver span {
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #AAFF00;
        }

        caption {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        span {
            border: 1px solid;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 12.5px;
            position: relative;
            top: -25px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            padding-bottom: 50px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <caption>Highest Fruit Score: <b>83</b></caption>
        <tr>
            <td class="silver"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGuyqx6.png"><br/><span>65</span></td>
            <td class="gold"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/uBDRMVu.png"><br/><span>83</span></td>
            <td class="bronze"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eOsWQe5.png"><br/><span>34</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

Your HTML should have a DOCTYPE declaration.  Nowadays, the HTML 5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) is considered standard practice.

You should [always declare a `charset`](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en), and the charset should be UTF-8.  The `<title>` element is [required](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element).

In an `<img>` tag, the [`alt` attribute is considered mandatory](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#general-guidelines), and in this case there are very obviously appropriate descriptions to assign to each image.

You are using a `<table>` to do the layout, for content which is not semantically tabular.  This is considered vulgar in HTML: the document should represent the meaning, and the layout should be performed using CSS.  (The user agent might not be a typical graphical browser; it might be a screen reader for the sight-impaired.)  The semantically appropriate element to use should be an `<ol>` ordered list.  The fruits should be listed in first, second, and third place in the document.

### CSS

For ease of maintenance, avoid repeating declarations.  For example, you can set the `font-family` just once on an ancestor element.  Also, you can write the `transform: scale(0.75)` declaration just once, using a `.silver, .bronze` selector.

How can we change the display order using CSS?  Using the [CSS `order` property](//stackoverflow.com/a/25077310/1157100) would be really nice, but it relies on [CSS flex boxes, which is a newer feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

```css
body {
    background-color: #AAFF00;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

div.fruits {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
div.fruits p {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 50px;
}
div.fruits p span.score {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol, li { /* CSS reset: make lists not work like lists */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol {
    display: flex;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
li.silver {
    order: -1;
}
.silver, .bronze {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}

li img {
    display: block;
}
li span.score {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 12.5px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
li.gold .score {
    background-color: gold;
}
li.silver .score {
    background-color: silver;
}
li.bronze .score {
    background-color: #CD7F32;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Top three fruits</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fruits">
        <p>Highest Fruit Score: <span class="score">83</span></p>
        <ol>
            <li class="gold"><img alt="banana" src="//i.imgur.com/uBDRMVu.png"> <span class="score">83</span></li>
            <li class="silver"><img alt="apple" src="//i.imgur.com/LGuyqx6.png"> <span class="score">65</span></li>
            <li class="bronze"><img alt="raspberry" src="//i.imgur.com/eOsWQe5.png"> <span class="score">34</span></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For compatibility, we can resort to using floats to put the silver element on the left.  A very unfortunate consequence of that hack is that the width of the list needs to be hard-coded to help position the floats properly.

```css
body {
    background-color: #AAFF00;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

div.fruits {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 750px; /* Unfortunately hard-coded width */
}
div.fruits p {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 50px;
}
div.fruits p span.score {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol, li { /* CSS reset: make lists not work like lists */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
}
.silver, .bronze {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}

/* Change the display order to silver-gold-bronze */
li.silver {
    float: left;
}
li.bronze {
    float: right;
}
ol:after {
    clear: both;
}

li span.score {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 12.5px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
li.gold .score {
    background-color: gold;
}
li.silver .score {
    background-color: silver;
}
li.bronze .score {
    background-color: #CD7F32;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Top three fruits</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fruits">
        <p>Highest Fruit Score: <span class="score">83</span></p>
        <ol>
            <li class="gold"><img alt="banana" src="//i.imgur.com/uBDRMVu.png"> <span class="score">83</span></li>
            <li class="silver"><img alt="apple" src="//i.imgur.com/LGuyqx6.png"> <span class="score">65</span></li>
            <li class="bronze"><img alt="raspberry" src="//i.imgur.com/eOsWQe5.png"> <span class="score">34</span></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I appreciate the detail.

I only have one problem. If I change a fruit's score to a number that exceeds double-digits then the score is no longer centered.

Comment: I've changed the score boxes from blocks to inline — see Rev 5.

Comment: That fixed one problem.

However, now the scores aren't centered and don't overlap the fruits. This is only able to be seen in full page mode.

Edit: You fixed it before I could post my comment.

Comment: That was a bug in Rev 4, which I think I fixed in Rev 5.